# Activate Apple Pay in Passbook

Tags: ios, iphone, payment, passbook, applepay

I have added a pass to passbook, which includes payment information.

Is it possible to pay from inside the passbook using Apple pay without creating an external payment application?

I mean, is it possible to display the Apple pay button programmatically inside the passbook/pass for payments?

What I have done:

- The server generates the passbook file and send the link to the iPhone
- The user clicks the link, automatically opens the passbook application and prompt user to add the pass to passbook application
- After adding the pass to passbook, users can see the payment link in pass
- Clicking on this link shall launch a payment application to show the payment details with an apple pay button to pay the bill.

My goal is to avoid these steps and get rid of payment application to pay the bill.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Short answer is currently no.  Don't know what we will see coming up in iOS9 next month but for now you could file an enhancement request through bugreport.apple.com